# Does Huffman coding always produce shorter codes than the Shannon code?

Tags: it.information-theory, prefix-free-code, huffman, shannon

Let $X\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ be a discrete random variable with $X\sim p$. 
Let $C$ be a code for $X$ with $l_i$ being the length $i$-th codeword and 
let $L(C)$ be the expected length of the code. 
The Shannon code produces a prefix code $C_{Sh}$ with 
the lengths of the codewords $l_i =\lceil \log_2 \frac{1}{p(i)}\rceil $. 
The Huffman code produces a prefix code $C_{Hu}$ which 
is minimal in expected length, but 
with non-explicit individual codeword lengths. 
Let $H(X)$ be the entropy of $X$.
We have 
$$H(X)\leq L(C_{Hu}) \leq L(C_{Sh})\leq H(X)+1.$$

**My Question:** 
Though Huffman code produces expected lengths at least as low as 
the Shannon code, are *all* of it's individual codewords shorter?

**Follow-up Question:** 
If not, do the lengths of all the codewords in a Huffman code 
at least satisfy the inequality:
$$ l^{Hu}_i<\log_2 \left(\frac{1}{p_i}\right)+1 ? $$

*(I'm looking for proofs/counterexamples.)*

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually problem 5.12 in Cover and Thomas's information theory textbook; show that the probability distribution ${1/12,1/4,1/3,1/3}$ gives a counterexample.

And if you want a really nice counterexample, consider the many non-isomorphic Huffman trees you can make when you have probabilities proportional to $$1,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34$$ (the Fibonacci series with an extra 1). Figure out what the maximum and minimum depths are for a Huffman tree with this probability distribution. This calculation will lead to a counterexample for your follow-up question.

Comment: Fibonacci frequencies were a very nice and crisp counterexample. Many thanks!